# Увеличить скорость отработки запросов

Tags: веб-программирование, php, оптимизация, sql, mysql

Доброго времени!

Немного о задаче:

Необходимо реализовать выборку статей в зависимости от выбранного раздела:

Разделы имеют древовидную структуру с неограниченной вложенностью,
в бд таблица разделов имеет поля id & parent_id, которые реализуют всю древовидность.

Сами статьи привязываются только к "конечным" разделам, которые не имеют подразделов.

Пример структуры разделов:

> - Раздел 1
> - - Раздел 1.1
> - - - Раздел 1.1.1 *(статьи здесь)*
> - - - Раздел 1.1.2 *(здесь)*
> - - Раздел 1.2
> - - - Раздел 1.2.1 *(здесь)*
> - - Раздел 1.3
> - - - Раздел 1.3.1 *(и здесь)*

Т.е. если выбран Раздел 1, то нужно получить id Разделов 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3.1 и вывести все статьи, которые к ним привязаны.
Проблема в том как это реализовано:
Выбираются в начале айдишники детей Раздела 1, потом айдишники их детей, итого 4 запроса(в конкретном случае).
Но на реальной базе в больших разделах до 100-500 запросов.
Плюс выборка статьей по через section_id IN (массив из 100+ элементов) долгое занятие.

Вопрос:

Как увеличить скорость работы, т.к. страница в итоге загружается за 10-15 секунд.

Comment: union+group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаю так строю массив(дерево)загоняю в кеш потом...

Comment: В итоге решил создать таблицу many-many статьи ко всем ее родительским разделам, тем самым убить и построение дерева и выборку через IN.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

В табличку с разделами добавить поле path, которое будет содержать путь от корневой до текущей категории.

Например в твоем примере у каждого раздела id от 1 до 8. Тогда поле path для Раздел 1.1.1 будет таким 1-2-3
При клике на Разделе 1 все id дочерних разделов будут выбраны таким запросом:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE path LIKE "$id%";
```

Таким образом у тебя будет только один запрос)